# Definition of convergence of a net

Tags: general-topology, terminology, nets

Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ be a set in $X$, where it is used $(I,\preceq)$ as a directed set. Which one of these definitions are correct, when we learn about the convergence of a net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ in a topological space $X$?

Let $y\in X$. The net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ is said to converge to $y$ if for every open set $U$ containing $y$ there exists $\alpha\in I$ such that ...

> (1) $\quad$ ... $x_\beta\in U$ for all $\beta\in I$ with $\beta\geq \alpha$.

or

> (2)  $\quad$ ... $x_\beta\in U$ for all $\beta\in I$ with $\alpha \preceq \beta$.

I think it is reasonable to take (2). In literature, they use the first one, where they used $\leq $ instead of $\preceq$, so probably they meant $\geq$ as an relation, the reversed symbol of $\leq$, not the sense of usual order, I don't know. That's why I ask.

Comment: Usually, the definition of $\geq$ is that $b\geq a$ if and only if $a\leq b$. Here, they presumably mean $\preceq$, so that they should use $\beta \succeq \alpha$ instead of $\beta\geq \alpha$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your comment. You mean number (2), right? You wrote ".. the definition of $\geq$ ..";  is $"\geq"$ here a relation, or the usual order (greater than or equal to)?

Comment: There is no "usual order" here! You have a set $I$ of indices; what "usual greater than or equal to" could you have on a random set of indices? You are usually given a partial order, which is denoted $\leq$, and you define $\geq$ in terms of $\leq$. When there is danger of confusion of a random partial order with a "standard" order, you may use $\preceq$ instead of $\leq$ to denote the relation, which case you would normally use $\succeq$ to play the equivalent role. So this is simply a typo, or sloppy notation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am sorry if I sound rude. I don't get it. I a slow learner. Here $I$ is any set, while $\preceq$ is a specified relation on $I$. Does $I$ have to be the set of "indices"? (I am not sure what its precise definition is). By "usual order", I mean something what we usually know about the symbol $\leq$, i.e. $1\leq 2$, etc. Could you confirm it for me that it is (2) in the post that's the right definition?

Comment: When you write $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$, you are saying that $I$ is a set, and for each element $\alpha\in I$ you have a term $x_{\alpha}$. The set $I$ is called an "Index set", and the objects $\alpha\in I$ are called indices. Because they show up as indices in your net. I know what you mean by "usual order", but here your set $I$ does not have to be a set of numbers. It can be a set of *anything* (you don't need to use numbers as indices; that's the point of nets!). So there is no "usual order" to be considered. The only order you have is the order they give you, $\preceq$.

Comment: (No, you don't sound rude; you sound lost)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin OK, I understand. I'll pick (2) as a definition. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Just as with sequences we take the *tail* of a net, so

$$\forall U \in \mathcal{U}(y): \exists \beta \in I: \forall \alpha \in I: (\alpha \succeq \beta \to x_\alpha \in U)$$

so we can find an index such that all terms with a "larger" (in the sense of how $(I, \preceq)$ is defined) index are in $U$. For classic sequences we use $I=\Bbb N$ and $\preceq = \le$ as we know it for natural numbers, but the power of nets is that we allow *any* directed set, also ones that are much larger than just countable and linearly ordered. We can have partially ordered ones, etc. as long as they are directed: $\forall \alpha, \beta \in I \exists \gamma \in I: \gamma \succeq \alpha \land \gamma \succeq \beta$, so that tails always "come together again", providing some sense of direction, going "forwards"...

Your $(2)$ is the same as $(1)$ but there the tail starts at $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are the indices in the tail. It's more common to use $\succeq$ for the reverse of $\preceq$, just like $\le$ and $\ge$ are both used on $\Bbb N$.